# Determine if there are two 2's next to each other in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Example output:

```
has22([1, 2, 2]) → True

has22([1, 2, 1, 2]) → False

has22([2, 1, 2]) → False
```

My code:

```
def has22(nums):

    for x in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[x] == 2 and (nums[x+1] == 2):
            return True
    return False
```

#Output: list index out of range

Comment: `for x in range(0, len(nums)-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line of your function, it shouold be: 
`for x in range(0, len(nums) - 1):` 
The reason for index out of range error is that at the last iteration your `nums[x+1]` gets out of range for the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),

```
def has22(l):
    for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]):
        if i == 2 and j == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

---

```
>>> has22([1, 2, 2])
True
>>> has22([1, 2, 1, 2])
False
>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

---

**Edit** : one-liner version suggested by @sabik

```
any(i == j == 2 for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]))
```

Comment: This can also be turned into a one-liner: `any(i == j == 2 for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]))`

Comment: As a side-note, it's better to avoid the variable name `l` because it can be similar to the number `1` in some fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because in the last iteration you are still trying to access the item  at x+1. Just do

```
for x in range(0, len(nums) - 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

def has22(lst):
    return any(k==2 and len(list(v)) ==2 for k,v in groupby(lst))
        
print(has22([1, 2, 2]))
print(has22([1, 2, 1, 2]))
print(has22([2, 1, 2]))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
False
```